# Plotting 2 y variables on a single plot in R

Tags: r

I want to have the years on the X-axis and sf_emissions and ny_emissions plotted as lines.

```
 years sf_emissions ny_emissions
1  1999     4740.273     4986.340
2  2002     3216.474     3586.434
3  2005     2959.778     3344.234
4  2008     4022.072     3429.964
```

This is my attempt. The data frame is called df2.

```
plot2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(years, sf_emissions, ny_emissions)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(reshape2)
df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars="years")

ggplot(df3, aes(x=years, y=value, colour = variable)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_line()
```

Comment: The first line worked when I changed id.vars=year to id.vars="years". But when I try to print the ggplot object I get "Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE"

Comment: It looks like the melt function doesn't work. When I run "df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars="years")" and then just enter "df3" I get "Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [8]"

Comment: do you have `reshape2`? also try it in a clean work station, i.e. restart R. This error is not something I get from running `melt` and must be something o do with your system.

Comment: @user1317221_G did you ever resolve your issue with melt? I'm experiencing the same thing

Comment: @user1317221_G I found someone else had hacked a solution... seems that the dimension attribute of the value column is not being correctly set. You can fix it after the melt command as follows:

Comment: lldf <- melt(df, id.vars = c('x'))
attr(lldf$value, "dim") <- dim(lldf)[1]

Answer (score 0):

Try to this if it works

`ggplot(df2, aes(years)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = sf_emissions, colour = "sf_emissions")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = ny_emissions, colour = "ny_emissions"))`